# How do you link ldap users with svn?

Tags: svn, redhat-enterprise-linux, openldap

I need to sync ldap users with the svn service configured on the RHEL 6.2 server I am using. Additionnaly it would be cool to be abble to control who can commit.
The ldap is working and users and group are being synchonized. The SVN is also working but there is only one user that is configured a la mano.

I have configured svn the following way in my RHEL box :

```
## as root
yum install subversion xinetd
# the svn group is an ldap group
adduser -m -g svn -s /bin/bash svn
## as svn
cd
svnadmin create /home/svn/repos
cd repos/conf
vi svnserve.conf # allow auth login
vi passwd        # add users
#- svntestuser = svntestuserpassword
## as root
vi /etc/xinetd.d/svnserve
#- service svn
#- {
#-  port = 3690
#-  socket_type = stream
#-  protocol = tcp
#-  wait = no
#-  user = svn
#-  server = /usr/bin/svnserve
#-  server_args = -i -r /home/svn
#- }
/etc/init.d/xinetd restart
```

Right now all additionnal users must be on the /home/svn/repos/passwd file. I think I need them to be sync with the svn group or another that I will create for the occasion.
I you have any improvment to the setup I am all ear.
Cheers,

EDIT 1 : I have as a prerequisite not to use an apache instance.
EDIT 2 : It seems that sasl authent can be used in svn and with the ldap, don't know how to yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two bad news for you:

- Svnserve'd Subversion using explicitly own **internal** user-database (password-db) and ACL-file (authz-db)
- You can't import users and groups from LAP *automagically* to authz-db or use LDAP instead of password-db

Two good news for you:

- Inside authz-db [you can define entity "groups"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html), which contain end-users and these groups can be used as keys in ACL-rules (use of individual users can be avoided completely)
- 3-rd party [Python-based script for uni-directional sync LDAP-groups](http://thoughtspark.org/node/26/) with content of `[groups]` section of authz-db exist and [it's available in Net](https://bitbucket.org/whitlockjc/jw-tools)

HTH

**EDIT**: In Subversion 1.8+ I see group-file, added as separate entity - you can transfer all groups definition in this file and don't worry to overwrite ACL-rules in the rest of authz-db on groups-sync

Comment: Thx, a little late but here is what I have : svnserve -> sasl-auth (checks with the ldap). As for the authorization I did use your good news :)